# How to change the text color a string in a set in a dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created a set 'result = new Set()' and I store values in the result set by calling the addValues function. This addValues function returns boolean if the values are added to the set or returns false.

Then I iterate the values stored in the result set and I use and angular dialog to display the values present. In the result set I have values like `this.result.add('Title')`, `this.result.add('Sub-Title')` and `this.result.add('End')` and I want these text should appear red in color in the angular dialog

My attempt:

```js
const test = this.addValues
if (test) {
  this.result.forEach(name => {
    this.values.push(name)
  })
  this.dialog.open(this.values)
}

public get addValues() {
  this.result.add('Title')
  this.result.add('a')
  this.result.add('b')
  this.result.add('Sub-Title')
  this.result.add('c')
  this.result.add('d')
  this.result.add('End')
  this.result.add('e')

  if (this.result.size > 0) {
    return true
  } else
    return false
}
```

Comment: what cant you add a class in the dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [this](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples) official Angular Material approach so as to create a dynamic dialog component with your predefined template and CSS preferences.

With your approach `this.dialog.open(this.values)` a dialog pop up is opened displaying `this.values` but you have no control on the template, nor the logic.

Comment: I have used dialog component i just need to change particular text color in the dialog.

Comment: So you can use style attribute at your dialog component's tags or add custom classes from a css file, which you load at dialog's @component contructor like [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Comment: That changes all the values color but i only need to this.result.add('Title'), this.result.add('Sub-Title') and this.result.add('End') to change these color to red and remaning default.

Comment: well, use something like  `<div *ngFor = let value of values [ngClass]=setClass(value)>{{value}}</div>`, and  in .ts  `setClass(val) { if (val ==='Title' || val === ...) return red_text}`, and in .css  `red_text {color:red}`